# Need the values that the user inputs to be added to the same array as predefined values

Tags: javascript, html

I need the values that the user inputs in the boxes to be added to the [people] array, so that they can be typed out on the page with the predefined values object1 and object2, together with if they are of legal age or not. I am unsure if I should be using another method for this, the assignment I received was vary vague.

Im new to coding so please forgive any errors.

```js
let nameElement = document.getElementById("UNameInput");
let faultElement = document.getElementById("errorOutput");
let ageElement = document.getElementById("AgeInput");
let clickElement = document.getElementById("button");
let passwordElement = document.getElementById("PasswordInput");
let corrElement = document.getElementById("output");



clickElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  let feedback = [];
  let people = [];


  let object1 = {
    UNameInput: "Marcus",
    ageElement: 33,
  }

  let object2 = {
    UNameInput: "Cihan",
    ageElement: 35,
  }

  people.push(object1, object2)

  console.log(people)


  /*
      people.push(new person1("Marcus", 33));
      people.push(new person2("Cihan", 35));
      */

  if (UNameInput.value === '' || UNameInput.value === null) {
    alert('Name input missing')
  } else if (AgeInput.value === '' || AgeInput.value === null) {
    alert('Age input missing')
  } else if (PasswordInput.value !== 'IHM') {
    alert('Password is not valid')

  } else if (AgeInput.value !== '') {
    if (ageElement.value < 18) {
      feedback.push(
        `Hi your name is ${UNameInput.value}. You are ${AgeInput.value} years old, which is not of legal age. Have a nice day!`
      );
      e.preventDefault()

    } else {
      feedback.push(
        `Hi your name is ${UNameInput.value}. You are ${AgeInput.value} years old, which makes you of legal age in Sweden. Have a nice day!`
      );
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }

  if (feedback.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    corrElement.innerText = feedback.join(", ")
  } else if (people.length > 0) {
    corrElement.innerText = people.join(", ")
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Inlämningsuppgift</title>


  <!-- Länk till JS-sourcet, det är denna koden som körs-->
  <script src="JSny copy 2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Div för error meddelanden, ifall det skulle vara så att de sker-->
  <div id="errorOutput"></div>

  <!-- P-tag för output av meddelanden, ID-attribut så att vi kan nå den specifikt ifrån JS-->
  <p id="output"></p>

  <!-- Nedanstående del består av 3 divvar, alla har input fält med varsitt ID så att de nås från JS-->
  <div>

    <label for="UNameInput">Name Input</label>
    <input id="UNameInput" name="name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="AgeInput">Age Input</label>
    <input id="AgeInput" name="age" type="number">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="PasswordInput">Password Input</label>
    <input id="PasswordInput" name="password" type="password">
  </div>

  <!-- Knappen som sätter igång JS skriptet, ID så att man kan targeta ifrån JS-->
  <button onclick="addToArray()" id="button">Submit</button>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can be typed out on the page" ? you define the people and feedback array in the function and by clicking the button, you reset the array. is this what your problem is?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what my problem is. I have added to pre-defined personas to the array, when the user types in their name and age, if the password is correct and all input fields are filled, when the button is pressed they should be typed out into the <p id = output>, together with if they're over 18 or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
let nameElement = document.getElementById("UNameInput");
let faultElement = document.getElementById("errorOutput");
let ageElement = document.getElementById("AgeInput");
let clickElement = document.getElementById("button");
let passwordElement = document.getElementById("PasswordInput");
let corrElement = document.getElementById("output");



clickElement.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    let feedback = [];
    let people = [];


   let object1 = {
       UNameInput: "Marcus",
       ageElement: 33,
   }

   let object2 = {
       UNameInput: "Cihan",
       ageElement: 35,
   }

   people.push(object1, object2)

   console.log(people)


/*
    people.push(new person1("Marcus", 33));
    people.push(new person2("Cihan", 35));
    */

    if (UNameInput.value === '' || UNameInput.value === null) {
       alert('Name input missing')
    }

    else if (AgeInput.value === '' || AgeInput.value === null) {
        alert('Age input missing')
    }
    else if (PasswordInput.value !== 'IHM') {
        alert('Password is not valid')

    } else if (AgeInput.value !== ''){
        if (ageElement.value < 18) {
                feedback.push ( 
                    `Hi your name is ${UNameInput.value}. You are ${AgeInput.value} years old, which is not of legal age. Have a nice day!`
                );
                e.preventDefault()
            
            }
        else {
                feedback.push(
                    `Hi your name is ${UNameInput.value}. You are ${AgeInput.value} years old, which makes you of legal age in Sweden. Have a nice day!`
                );
                let newObj = {
                    UNameInput: UNameInput.value,
                    ageElement: AgeInput.value,
                }
                people.push(newObj);
                e.preventDefault()
            }
    }

    if (feedback.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault()
        corrElement.innerText = feedback.join(", ")
    }

    else if (people.length > 0) {
        corrElement.innerText = people.join (", ")
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please, I'm uncertain on what you mean.

Comment: @cossab please use code from the above code. I updated the answer with full code.

Comment: Will this code put the predefined 'object 1, object 2' into the same array as what the user types in, and then put into the <p>?

Comment: [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] this is the only thing that shows up on my live server when I press the button.

Comment: Yes, because you code is doing that, this line: corrElement.innerText = people.join (", ")

Comment: How shall I change the code, to get the actual names and ages of them showing instead, along with their legal age?